# EmployeeDocuments table can not be created in the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to create database and related tables. Everything works except from 'EmployeeDocuments' table (database and 4 tables were created) . It gives an error like:

> There is already an object named 'FK_Employees_Companies1' in the database.

My codes are as below:

```
private void UserEntryForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfDBExist();
    }
    int i;

    private void CheckIfDBExist()
    {

        SqlConnection tmpConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;user=sa;pwd=123");

        string sqlCreateDBQuery = string.Format("if not exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'Devrimer_v2222')create database Devrimer_v2222");

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn);

        string constr = Tools.Baglanti.ConnectionString.ToString();

        try
        {
            tmpConn.Open();
            int sonuc = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (sonuc != 0) 
            {
                tmpConn.Close();

                string query = "if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Companies' ";
                query += ")";
                query += "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies]([Id][int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,";
                query += "[Name][nvarchar](100) NULL,";
                query += "[Adress][nvarchar](500) NULL,";
                query += "[TelNo][char](20) NULL,";
                query += "[Active][bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT[DF_Companies_Active] DEFAULT((1)),";
                query += "CONSTRAINT[PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id] ASC ) WITH(PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,";
                query += "IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,";
                query += "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON[PRIMARY] ) ON[PRIMARY]";
                query += " SET ANSI_PADDING OFF";


                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                string docQuery = "if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Documents' ";
                docQuery += ")";
                docQuery += "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents]([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,";
                docQuery += "[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,";
                docQuery += "[Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,";
                docQuery += "[ValidPeriod] [int] NULL,";
                docQuery += "[PeriodType] [nchar](10) NULL,";
                docQuery += "[Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)), ";
                docQuery += "CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ";
                docQuery += "STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ";
                docQuery += "IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ";
                docQuery += "ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ";
                docQuery += " ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(docQuery))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                string EmpQuery = "if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Employees' ";
                EmpQuery += ")";
                EmpQuery += "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]( [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[SurName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[Gender] [tinyint] NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[MaritalStatus] [tinyint] NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[Tckn] [char](11) NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[ReportTo] [int] NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[BirthDate] [date] NULL, ";
                EmpQuery += "[TelNo] [char](20) NULL, ";
                EmpQuery += "[Adress] [nvarchar](500) NULL, ";
                EmpQuery += "[Email] [nvarchar](250) NULL, ";
                EmpQuery += "[CompanyID] [int] NULL,";
                EmpQuery += "[StartWorkingDate] [date] NULL, ";
                EmpQuery += "[Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Employees_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)), ";
                EmpQuery += " CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ";
                EmpQuery += "STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ";
                EmpQuery += "IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ";
                EmpQuery += "ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ";
                EmpQuery += "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] ";
                EmpQuery += ";";
                EmpQuery += "SET ANSI_PADDING OFF ";
                EmpQuery += "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Companies1] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([Id]) ";
                EmpQuery += ";";
                EmpQuery += "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Companies1] ";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(EmpQuery))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                string userQuery = "if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Users' ";
                userQuery += ")";
                userQuery += "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ";
                userQuery += "[EmployeID] [int] NULL, ";
                userQuery += "[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL, ";
                userQuery += "[Password] [nchar](10) NULL, ";
                userQuery += "[Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Users_Aktif]  DEFAULT ((1)), ";
                userQuery += " CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ";
                userQuery += "STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ";
                userQuery += "IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ";
                userQuery += "ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,";
                userQuery += "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] ";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(userQuery))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                string docEmpQuery = "if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'EmployeeDocuments' ";
                docEmpQuery += ")";
                docEmpQuery += "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments]( [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL, ";
                docEmpQuery += "[DocumentID] [int] NOT NULL, ";
                docEmpQuery += "[GivenDate] [date] NULL, ";
                docEmpQuery += "[LastValidDate] [date] NULL, ";
                docEmpQuery += "CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeDocuments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [EmployeeID] ASC, ";
                docEmpQuery += "[DocumentID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ";
                docEmpQuery += "STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ";
                docEmpQuery += "IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ";
                docEmpQuery += "ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,";
                docEmpQuery += "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]";
                docEmpQuery += ";";
                docEmpQuery += "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDocuments_Documents1] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentID])REFERENCES [dbo].[Documents] ([Id]) ";
                docEmpQuery += ";";
                docEmpQuery += "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDocuments_Documents1] ";
                docEmpQuery += "; ";
                docEmpQuery += "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDocuments_Employees1] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].Employees] ([Id]) ";
                docEmpQuery += ";";
                docEmpQuery += "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDocuments_Employees1] ";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(docEmpQuery))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception hata)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format(sqlCmd.CommandText.ToString() + "\n\nHata: " + hata.Message.ToString()));
        }
        finally
        {
            tmpConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use MyDbUtils.exe and exported all procedures and triggers, and included syntax for the tables and database creation ,
It worked very well;

I have used a method (SQLTEXTexec ()) to run the all text string:

then;
 used CheckIfDBExist()) method to create database and tables;
 worked fine so far 
 ;

```
private void SQLTEXTexec(string sql, SqlConnection conn)
        {
            string sqlBatch = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, conn);
            conn.Open();
            sql += "\nGO";   // make sure last batch is executed.
            try
            {
                foreach (string line in sql.Split(new string[2] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    if (line.ToUpperInvariant().Trim() == "GO")
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = sqlBatch;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlBatch = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sqlBatch += line + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

---

```
    private void CheckIfDBExist()
        {

            SqlConnection tmpConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;user=sa;pwd=123");
            //("if not exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'Devrimer_v2222' ) create database Devrimer_v2222");

            string sqlCreateDBQuery = string.Format("if not exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'Devrimer_v2222')create database Devrimer_v2222");

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn);

            string constr = Tools.Baglanti.ConnectionString.ToString();

            try
            {
                tmpConn.Open();

                int sonuc = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (sonuc != 0) // database i silince çalışacak...


                {

                    tmpConn.Close();

                    string query = @"if not exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'Devrimer_v2222')
create database Devrimer_v2222 
GO

use Devrimer_v2222 
if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Companies')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Adress] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [TelNo] [char](20) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Companies_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO 

USE Devrimer_v2222
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Companies_Delete]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Companies_Delete] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Companies_Delete]
@Id int
as 
delete Companies
where 
Id=@Id
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Companies_Insert]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Companies_Insert] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Companies_Insert]
--@Id int, primary kolonu almıyoruz.
@Name nvarchar(100),
@Adress nvarchar(500),
@TelNo char(20),
@Active bit
as
insert Companies 
values (@Name,@Adress,@TelNo,@Active)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Companies_Select]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Companies_Select] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER  proc [dbo].[prc_Companies_Select]
as
select * from Companies where Active=1
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Companies_Update]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Companies_Update] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Companies_Update]
@Id int,
@Name nvarchar(100),
@Adress nvarchar(500),
@TelNo char(20),
@Active bit 
as
update Companies 
set
--Id=@Id, 
Name=@Name, 
Adress=@Adress,
TelNo=@TelNo,
Active=@Active
where
Id=@Id
GO

USE Devrimer_v2222

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Companies]
           ([Name]
           ,[Adress]
           ,[TelNo]
           ,[Active])
     VALUES
           ('Anagold','Erzincan',0543456,1)
GO


use Devrimer_v2222
if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Documents')
begin
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ValidPeriod] [int] NULL,
    [PeriodType] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Documents_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

use Devrimer_v2222
GO


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Documents_Delete]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Documents_Delete] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Documents_Delete]
@Id int
as 
delete Documents
where 
Id=@Id
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Documents_Insert]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Documents_Insert] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Documents_Insert]
--@Id int, primary kolonu almıyoruz.
@Name nvarchar(50),
@Description nvarchar(500),
@ValidPeriod int,
@periodType char(10),
@Active bit
as
insert Documents 
values (@Name,@Description,@ValidPeriod,@periodType,@Active)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Documents_Select]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Documents_Select] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER  proc [dbo].[prc_Documents_Select]
as
select * from Documents where Active=1
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Documents_Update]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Documents_Update] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Documents_Update]
@Id int,
@Name nvarchar(50),
@Description nvarchar(500),
@ValidPeriod int,
@PeriodType nchar(10),
@Active bit 
as
update Documents 
set
--Id=@Id, 
Name=@Name, 
Description=@Description,
ValidPeriod=@ValidPeriod,
PeriodType=@PeriodType,
Active=@Active
where
Id=@Id
GO

use Devrimer_v2222
GO

if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Employees')
begin
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SurName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Gender] [tinyint] NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Tckn] [char](11) NULL,
    [ReportTo] [int] NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NULL,
    [TelNo] [char](20) NULL,
    [Adress] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] NULL,
    [StartWorkingDate] [date] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Employees_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Companies1] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Companies1]
GO
use Devrimer_v2222
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Employees_Delete]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Employees_Delete] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Employees_Delete]
@Id int
as 
delete Employees
where 
Id=@Id
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Employees_Insert]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Employees_Insert] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Employees_Insert]
--@Id int, primary kolonu almıyoruz.
@Name nvarchar(50),
@SurName nvarchar(50),
@Title nvarchar(50),
@Gender char(10),
@MaritalStatus char(10),
@Tckn char(11),
@ReportTo nvarchar(50),
@BirthDate date,
@TelNo char(20),
@Adress nvarchar(500),
@Email nvarchar(250),
@CompanyID int,
@StartWorkingDate date,
@Active bit
as
insert Employees 
values (@Name,@SurName,@Title,@Gender,@MaritalStatus,@Tckn,@ReportTo,@BirthDate,
@TelNo,@Adress,@Email,@CompanyID,@StartWorkingDate,@Active)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Employees_Select]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Employees_Select] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Employees_Select]
as
Select
Id,
Name,
SurName,
Title,

case MaritalStatus
when 1 then 'Married'
when 2 then 'Single' 
end as MaritalStatus,

case Gender
when 1 then 'Male'
when 2 then 'Female'
end as Gender,

Tckn,
ReportTo,
BirthDate,
TelNo,
Adress,
Email,
CompanyID,
StartWorkingDate

from Employees where Active = 1
GO

use Devrimer_v2222
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees]
           ([Name]
           ,[SurName]
           ,[Title]
           ,[Gender]
           ,[MaritalStatus]
           ,[Tckn]
           ,[ReportTo]
           ,[BirthDate]
           ,[TelNo]
           ,[Adress]
           ,[Email]
           ,[CompanyID]
           ,[StartWorkingDate]
           ,[Active])
     VALUES
           ('Özgür','Acar','MadenMühendisi',1,1,12345,1,'01.03.1974',1234,'Adres','oo@c.c',1,'01.03.2002',1)
GO
use Devrimer_v2222

if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'Users')
begin
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeID] [int] NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Users_Aktif]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
USE [Devrimer_v2222]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Users_Delete]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Users_Delete] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Users_Delete]
@Id int
as 
delete Users
where 
Id=@Id
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Users_Entry]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Users_Entry] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Users_Entry]
@unm nvarchar (50),
@pas nvarchar (15)
as
select * from Users
where UserName=@unm and Password=@pas and Active=1
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Users_Insert]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Users_Insert] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Users_Insert]
@EmployeID int,
@UserName nvarchar (50),
@Password nvarchar (10),
@Active bit
as
insert Users
values (@EmployeID, @UserName,@Password,@Active)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Users_Select]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Users_Select] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Users_Select]
as
select * from Users where Active=1
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_Users_Update]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_Users_Update] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_Users_Update]
@Id int,
@EmployeID int,
@UserName nvarchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(50),
@Active bit
as
update Users 
set
--Id=@Id, 
EmployeID=@EmployeID, 
UserName=@UserName,
Password=@Password

where
Id=@Id
GO
use Devrimer_v2222
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
           ([EmployeID]
           ,[UserName]
           ,[Password]
           ,[Active])
     VALUES
           (1,1,1,1)
GO

use Devrimer_v2222
if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'EmployeeDocuments')
begin
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments](
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GivenDate] [date] NULL,
    [LastValidDate] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeDocuments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeID] ASC,
    [DocumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDocuments_Documents1] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Documents] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDocuments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDocuments_Documents1]
GO
use Devrimer_v2222
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Delete]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Delete] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Delete]
@EmployeID int,
@DocumentID int
as 
delete EmployeeDocuments
where 
DocumentID=@DocumentID and EmployeeID=@EmployeID
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Insert]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Insert] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Insert]

@EmployeeID int,
@DocumentID int,
@GivenDate date,
@LastValidDate date
as
insert EmployeeDocuments  
values (@EmployeeID,@DocumentID,@GivenDate,@LastValidDate)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Select]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Select] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Select]
as
select * from EmployeeDocuments
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Update]') AND type = N'P') 
exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Update] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prc_EmployeeDocuments_Update]
@EmployeeID int,
@DocumentID int,
@GivenDate date,
@LastValidDate date
as
update EmployeeDocuments 
set
--Id=@Id, 
EmployeeID=@EmployeeID, 
DocumentID=@DocumentID,
GivenDate=@GivenDate,
LastValidDate=@LastValidDate

where
@EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
GO

use Devrimer_v2222

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg_Delete_Companies]')) 
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Delete_Companies]
GO
create trigger [dbo].[trg_Delete_Companies]
on [dbo].[Companies]
instead of delete
as
declare @Id int
select @Id= Id from deleted -- 1. Atama yöntemi
set @Id =(select Id from deleted) -- 2. Atama Yöntemi - tek kayıt varsa 

update Companies set Active=0 where Id=@Id
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg_Delete_Documents]')) 
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Delete_Documents]
GO
create trigger [dbo].[trg_Delete_Documents]
on [dbo].[Documents]
instead of delete
as
declare @Id int
select @Id= Id from deleted -- 1. Atama yöntemi
set @Id =(select Id from deleted) -- 2. Atama Yöntemi - tek kayıt varsa 

update Documents set Active=0 where Id=@Id
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg_Delete_Employees]')) 
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Delete_Employees]
GO
create trigger [dbo].[trg_Delete_Employees]
on [dbo].[Employees]
instead of delete
as
declare @Id int
select @Id= Id from deleted -- 1. Atama yöntemi
set @Id =(select Id from deleted) -- 2. Atama Yöntemi - tek kayıt varsa 

update Employees set Active=0 where Id=@Id
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trg_Delete_Users]')) 
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Delete_Users]
GO
create trigger [dbo].[trg_Delete_Users]
on [dbo].[Users]
instead of delete
as
declare @Id int
--select @Id= Id from deleted -- 1. Atama yöntemi
set @Id =(select Id from deleted) -- 2. Atama Yöntemi - tek kayıt varsa 

update Users set Active=0 where Id=@Id ";

                    SqlConnection con = Tools.Baglanti;
                    SQLTEXTexec(query, con);
                }
            }


            catch (Exception hata)
            {
              //  MessageBox.Show(string.Format(sqlCmd.CommandText.ToString() + "\n\nHata: " + hata.Message.ToString()));
            }
            finally
            {
                tmpConn.Close();
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't fine any better way so far. ver useful tool that I have used https://mydbutils.codeplex.com/ Thanks to everybody who helps we amateurs.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you check to see if the table exists before creating it, yet you always try and create the constraints regardless of whether or not they exist, you have something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Employees')
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees (....)
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employees WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ....
```

With this syntax it is only the statement immediately following the `IF` that will be conditional, a simply example would be:

```
IF 1 = 0
PRINT '1';
PRINT '2';
```

Which will simply print "2". If you want to have multiple statements executed conditionally, you need to wrap them in a statement block (`BEGIN/END`)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Employees')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees (....)
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Employees WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ....
END
```

For what it is worth, you could use a verbatim string literal to make everything a bit more legible (and easier to edit). e.g.

```
string query = @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Employees')
                BEGIN
                    CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees (....)
                    ALTER TABLE dbo.Employees WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ....
                END;";
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, all you have given me some Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing you constraint name, seems its created with same name in your database